Constructing a minimum-volume outer approximation polytope with fewer facets
I am tackling the following problem:
Given a set of points $D \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and their convex hull, represented with $n$ facets, I want to construct a convex polytope $P$ with at most $m<n$ facets (not necessarily induced by points in $D$) that:

Contains all points in $D$ (i.e., forms an outer approximation).
Minimizes the increase in volume relative to the original convex hull, making $P$ as tight as possible among polytopes with $m$ or fewer facets.
Can be computed efficiently in polynomial time with respect to the
number of points in $D$ and the dimension $d$.

I suspect this problem may be computationally hard, but my intuition might be off. I'm also open to approximate or heuristic solutions. For example, I’m aware of the John ellipsoid as a related concept, but I am more interested in polytopes. In addition, the John ellipsoid can sometimes produce a considerably larger volume than the original convex hull, making it less ideal for my purposes. Are there known methods or approaches that could help, particularly for cases where $m$ is relatively small?
